# select statement within if for comparison

Tags: sql, select, plsql

I would need to compare two select statement outputs and compare them to get a result. But would like to know if this query has any syntax errors, any other alternative methods if suggested will be helpful as well.

```
if (      select h_s_effective_dt from h_s_protocol where appr_stat_id = 'AP' > select h_s_effective_dt from h_s_protocol where appr_stat_id = 'TR'     )

then appr_stat_id = 'AP' else appr_stat_id = 'TR'
end if
```

Comment: Surely it would have been quicker to check your syntax by feeding the code to your database than even to *post* this question, much less receive answers to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any errors.

But use it like this.

```
qry1 = select h_s_effective_dt from h_s_protocol where appr_stat_id = 'AP';

qry2 = select h_s_effective_dt from h_s_protocol where appr_stat_id = 'TR';

If(qry1>qry2)
then appr_stat_id = 'AP'
else appr_stat_id = 'TR' 
end if
```

Looks more cleaner

Comment: use `INTO` clause if you are using pl/sql and want to store value in a variable.your code would generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. 
 
By storing a value into a variable you can use it more easy on multiple locations. 
 
Also make sure that `appr_stat_id` is declared, else you can not store anything in it. The database needs to know if `appr_stat_id` is a `VARCHAR2` or `CHAR` or a `NUMBER`.

```
DECLARE
    valueX VARCHAR2(100) := '';
    valueY VARCHAR2(100) := '';
    appr_stat_id VARCHAR2(100) := '';

BEGIN
    -- Store the value in valueX or valueY, giving this sequence will only give one line back. 
    SELECT h_s_effective_dt INTO valueX FROM h_s_protocol WHERE appr_stat_id = 'AP';
    SELECT h_s_effective_dt INTO valueY FROM h_s_protocol WHERE appr_stat_id = 'TR';

    IF (valueX>valueY) THEN 
        appr_stat_id = 'AP'; 
    ELSE
        appr_stat_id = 'TR';
    END IF; 
END;
/
```